# Storing rotation of child relative to its parent not working properly in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am trying to store relative rotation of child game objects, so that I can calculate their world rotation when needed as I am deleting those because of no use, for that I am storing the rotation from their forward to parent's forward, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
// store relative rotation
var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(child.forward, parent.forward);

// get world rotation
var childWorldRot = parent.rotation * rot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution involving quaternion transformations but this is simple and should do the trick:

```
// store relative directions
var refUp = parent.InverseTransformDirection(child.up);
var refForward = parent.InverseTransformDirection(child.forward);

// get world rotation
var childWorldRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(parent.TransformDirection(refForward), parent.TransformDirection(refUp));
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Are you talking about while storing relative rotation info of child, do I need to use `TransformDirection`? if yes how'd calculate child's world rotation at runtime using the result of `TransformDirection`?

Comment: I have changed my answer. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: it worked, though sometimes the values are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Transform.localRotation`. It is relative to parent.
I'm not sure I quite understand what your end goal is, but keep in mind that `Transform.rotation` already is in world space.

```cs
// store relative rotation
var rot = child.localRotation;

// get world rotation
var childWorldRot = child.rotation;
```

Comment: I know `Transform.rotation` is world rotation, but I can't use child transform to get its world rotation as I am deleting child game objects after getting their relative rotations, I want to calculate their world rotation at run time.
FYI: parent game object is a moving object.

Comment: Ahh, ok then. I won't edit my answer, since I'm not in a position to test, but your approach seems valid. I think you just need to swap the order of arguments to `FromToRotation`.

Comment: OK, no, on second thought, you need one more vector to specify an unambiguos rotation. E.g. a forward and an up vector. I'd suggest storing the rotation quaternion, or the euler angles.

Comment: I tried this already, didn't work `Quaternion.Euler(childEulerAngles)`